# A solution of generalized Burgers' Equation in the form of a function of $x/t$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Suppose the conservation law $u_t+f(u)_{x}=0$ has a solution of the form $u(x,t)=v(x/t).$  Show that the profile of v is given by $v(s)=(f')^{-1}(s)$,
>   and $s=(u_{L}+u_{R})$ is the shock speed.

My attempt so far:
Starting with Part 1, supposing there is a solution of the form $u(x,t)=v(x/t)$, we have that $u_t=-\frac{x}{t^2}v'$ and $f(u)_{x}=f'(v(x/t))*\frac{1}{t}v'$.  Substituting this into the conservation law yields,
$-\frac{x}{t^2}v'+f'*\frac{1}{t}v'=0.$

This is where I get stuck...

Answer (score 1):

The equation $$-\frac{x}{t^2}v'+f'(v(x/t))\frac{1}{t}v'=0$$ factors. Apparently, we are supposed to ignore the constant solution $v'=0$. Then the equation simplifies to 
$$f'(v(x/t)) = x/t$$
which, after introducing the notation $s=x/t$, is exactly $v(s)=(f')^{-1}(s)$.